# Using reflection, how do I find the method an interface is implementing when it's implementing another interface

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Let's say I have two interfaces:

```cs
public interface IDeclaring
{
    String GetValue();
}

public interface IImplementing : IDeclaring
{
    String IDeclaring.GetValue() => "IDerived";
}
```

I'm writing a library that implements interfaces at runtime and therefore needs to understand which interface methods need implementing, and which are already implemented.

Using reflection, I now have one `MethodInfo` per interface, say `delcaringMethodInfo` and `implementingMethodInfo` but I can't figure out how to get the information that the latter implements the former.

There's `MethodInfo.GetBaseDefinition` but that doesn't work on interfaces.

That information must somewhere be present and accessible though.

It would probably be enough to be able to check if the two `MethodInfo`s have the same signature, but I don't know how to do that either easily as that's not trivial. I suspect I need to check whether they have the same parameters and parameter modifiers.

Comment: This may well be an oversight in the reflection interfaces. Normally `Type.GetInterfaceMap()` helps with such things, but that currently still throws if the input type is an interface itself -- despite explicit interface implementations being a thing now.

Comment: @JeroenMostert The information must be present in an assembly somewhere, even if .NET doesn't provide an API to get at it. Do you know where and how it is stored?

Comment: No, unfortunately the feature writeup doesn't include the runtime details (as they sometimes do for simpler features). Of course you can reverse it yourself through an IL disassembler like ILSpy, but this is hardly a realistic way to get at the data without an API.

Comment: Oh wait, it seems all that was done on the IL level is relax the restriction on concrete methods in interfaces (plus a more complicated method dispatch algorithm, but that doesn't change the basics). This means an explicit implementation of a default interface method in an *interface* is exactly the same thing as in a *class*. Which is neat, but kind of doesn't help you if the APIs have no support. Decompiling the whole assembly is technically an option...

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think I'll go a different route: Creating an abstract base first. On that level, I just need to know which method does have an implementation but not which interface implements it. Then from a second derived class I call the abstract base (which then is just `base.Foo`). That could even be done with source generators. I already was at that point earlier but then concluded I could do without have two types per interface. I guess not.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Forget what I claimed earlier, the private field still just contains the method itself. I was confused because the method's debug string suggests it's the base method.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeroen says, there is no proper API to get at that information.

On the assembly level, this information appears as a *declaration* in the method body:

```
.method private hidebysig specialname virtual final 
        instance string  I.get_Name() cil managed
{
  .override I::get_Name
  // Code size       6 (0x6)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void [System.Runtime]System.NotImplementedException::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  throw
} // end of method D::I.get_Name
```

But those declarations can't be retrieved from any API I know of either.

The `MethodInfo.GetBaseDefinition` method returns the method itself in case of interfaces.